# Change How JWPlayer Replaces DIV

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Using JWplayer and I notice when it (the javascript) loads the player it replaces the < div >
with a < p > which causes a space in the container.

If you're not familiar with how JWplayer works, you add a < div > with a specific ID. Then in the Javascript you just tell it to use that ID. When the player is loaded it will just replace that < div > with the player.

My issue is I can't sift through the .js file to make it stop adding this < p > tag. N00b, i know.

I appreciate any help one this. You can download the JWplayer for free to take a peak at the JS file. I'm using version 5.

Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? The player doesn't add < p > to the best of my knowledge.